# mocha test (and babel) using global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, babeljs

I am writing library using es6, transpiling it with babel via webpack and npm.
The problem is, that my lib is dependent on some code, that I can not change but need to use. I don't know how to load **var stuff** (from the following example) in my tests so that it is visible for the module.

See the example:

**external-stuff.js** - this one can not be changed and is loaded before my lib is loaded on prod env.

```
var stuff = {
    get some()  { return "some"; }
    get stuff() { return "stuff"; }
}
```

**some-module.js** - this is one of the modules in the library

```
export class foo {
    static get whatever() { return stuff.some; }
    static get whichever() { return stuff.stuff; }
}
```

**test**

```
import {foo} from "../src/foo.js";

let assert = require('assert');

describe('foo', function() {
    describe('#whatever()', function() {
        it("should do some", function () {
            assert.equals(foo.whatever(), "some");
        });
    });
});
```

If I run this I get "ReferenceError: stuff is not defined"

I already tried to define "stuff" in before() hook, but no success.

Comment: did you import `stuff` from external-stuff.js to some-module.js ? I don't see any imports so I am asking

Comment: @ArpitSolanki no I didn't because as you notice stuff.js is not es6 module, it is simply a global variable.

Comment: How is this global module loaded? Can you tell?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki in reality it is hard included in java module that uses rhino for js parsing and we are only loading the resulting transpiled library into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found a solution that's 'good enough'. I am not sure it would be sufficient for some advanced library though.

I have created file called globals.js

```
var g = typeof(window) === 'undefined' ? global : window;

// Dependencies - add as many global stuff as needed
g.stuff= typeof(stuff) === 'undefined' ? {} : stuff;
```

And I import this 'es6module' at the beginning of test

```
import * as globals from "../lib/global/globals"
import {foo} from "../src/foo.js";
```

And then I use [node-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-import) npm module with which I load the global to the tests in beforeEach hook.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    global.stuff = imports.module("lib/global/stuff.js").stuff;
});
```

This is perfect for unit testing because I can also mock stuff. And its even more awesome because this way I have a place where I 'define' global dependencies. It would be nice to improve on it and make it per es6modul dependencies... and build on it something fancy... ya know.. dependency injection.

complete test

```
require('node-import'); // +

import * as globals from "../lib/global/globals";  // +
import {foo} from "../src/foo.js";

let assert = require('assert');

describe('foo', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {  // +
        global.stuff = imports.module("lib/global/stuff.js").stuff;  // +
    });  // +

    describe('#whatever()', function() {
        it("should do some", function () {
            assert.equals(foo.whatever(), "some");
        });
    });
});
```